# how to find textbox.text in txt file

Tags: c#, arrays, text, lambda

this code does not work

I want to fine textbox1.text value in txt file

```
    string[] array = File.ReadLines(Application.StartupPath + "\\1.txt").ToArray();


        var target = textBox1.Text;
        var results = Array.FindAll(array, s => s.Equals(target));

        if (results.Equals(target))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("find");
        }
        else 
        {
            MessageBox.Show("not find");

        }
```

Comment: use `if (target.Any())`

Comment: Did you consider the case sensitivity of string.Equals? "abcd" is not equal to "Abcd"

Comment: I did not get...

Comment: @Steve no not equal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Array.FindAll](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1kkxfxdd(v=vs.110).aspx) returns an array of the found matches. You cannot use Array.Equals to check again if you have found the item because you are comparing an array of strings with a single string. Of course the answer is always false.

Instead you write

```
var target = textBox1.Text;
var results = Array.FindAll(array, s => s.Equals(target));

if (results.Length > 0)
{
    MessageBox.Show($"Found {results.Length} matches");
}
else 
{
    MessageBox.Show("No matches found");
}
```

Also consider that string.Equals is case sensitive and thus it doesn't find as equal two strings like "ABCD" and "abcd".